# WakeLock-related Mandelbug: does WakeLock.acquire() always succeed?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock, mandelbug

**The Problem**

I've been developing for Android for quite some time now. One of the programs I've developed makes heavy use of [WakeLocks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). It usually perfectly (often for days or weeks at a time, a requirement of the program), but very rarely I notice peculiar behaviour in this code:

```
acquireWakeLock(wakeLockManager)

    // Preconditions
    assertFalse("Wake lock already acquired.", hasWakeLock());
    assertNotNull("Wake lock manager not provided.", wakeLockManager);

    // Acquire a wake lock.
    wakeLock = wakeLockManager.newPartialWakeLock(DEBUG_TAG);
    wakeLock.acquire();

    // Postconditions
    assertTrue("Wake Lock should be held!", hasWakeLock());
```

Where `hasWakeLock()` simply returns the result of `(wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld())` and `wakeLockManager.newPartialWakeLock(DEBUG_TAG)` encapsulates the standard "get the PowerManager and then return a wake lock" code. For the purposes of testing, the assert statements are JUnit assert methods so I think we can assume that they are correct.

The problem with the code is this: the final assertion - `assertTrue(hasWakeLock())` - seems to fail every few weeks with very little explanation. It means that I have three possible issues here: (1) the wake lock is never retrieved at all from the PowerManager (2) that I have a concurrency issue that on rare occasions takes effect just before the postcondition but after the call to `acquire()`, or that (3) `acquire()` is sometimes faulty.

**Investigation of the Problem**

As stated above, I have three potential issues that may be occurring that I am investigating / have investigated:

*Hypothesis 1: Wake Lock not returned*:

Were this the case then I would see a null pointer exception. It can't be that.

*Hypothesis 2: I have a concurrency issue*:

A just-conducted formal verification proof of all places involved in acquiring and releasing `wakeLock` strongly leads me to believe that this is not the case. In the case that my proof is faulty then I may have a concurrency issue, but it is then truly insidious and difficult to find.

*Hypothesis 3: WakeLock.acquire() is faulty, and [despite what the documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#acquire%28%29) it sometimes can fail to acquire the lock*:

I dislike this hypothesis because with all of the Android users our there *someone* aside from myself must have noticed this by now and it is almost always the developer's code, not the library or OS code, that is faulty. Then again, stranger things have happened and this might be a genuine Android bug, albeit a rarely exhibited one. If this hypothesis is true then acquire() is simply not acquiring the wake lock and this would explain the behaviour I'm seeing.

So StackOverflow, what could be causing this problem? What do you think is wrong? Am I missing something obvious, or could this be a genuine problem with Android's wake locks?

Comment: Are you seeing this bug on devices from different vendors? Or maybe  you managed to repro this on emulator too?

Comment: Only on the Google IO device. I'm running a custom version of Android 2.1 on it; the custom version only modifies Bluetooth code.

Comment: If this bug is as rare as you describe it, my first bet would be to repro it on another vendor's devices or same device with Android 2.2.

Comment: If I had another type of device available to me I would do so. Unfortunately I can't use the emulator either as this program so heavily relies on sensor data.

Comment: How about acquire and release WakeLock many times in a loop. Just a plain simple app with service and background thread that does this. Maybe you'll be able to repro this issue faster then once in a week. If so, I'd be happy to try the app on one of my devices.

Comment: That's an interesting thought but unfortunately other priorities have come up. I'll keep that in mind and try it here if my coworkers and/or I get new hardware in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this was indeed a concurrency issue. I overlooked the fact that a relevant method could be called from a non-synchronized location in a separate thread - an obvious problem in a highly multithreaded environment!